# A singleton list of list is automatically decomposed

Tags: css, list, sass

In SCSS, I have a mixin that takes a list and checks its length, as follows:

```
@mixin foo($list){
  @debug length($list);
}
```

When I pass a list of more than two lists `($a, $a)` as follows,

```
$a: (1, 2, 3);
@include foo(($a, $a));
```

the `length` function counts that there are two `$a`-s inside of `($a, $a)`, and returns the result:

```
DEBUG: 2
```

but when I pass a list that consists of a single list `($a)` as follows,

```
@include foo(($a));
```

it seems that the list `$a` is decomposed, and the `length` function counts the three elements in `$a` instead of counting the number of `$a`-s in `($a)`, and returns the result:

```
DEBUG: 3
```

It does not make difference if I embed the list further. All of the following return the same result:

```
@include foo($a);
@include foo(($a));
@include foo((($a)));
```

Is this an expected feature? Why does this happen, and is there a way to return `1` in these cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Sass, parentheses are used to indicate order of operations, not to indicate that you have a list with a single element.

In Sass 3.3, adding a trailing comma will automatically turn your value into a list:

```
$foo: 1, ;
```

What you may be wanting to do instead is have your mixin take a variable number of arguments and use them as a list.  That would look like this:

```
@mixin foo($list...){
  @debug length($list);
}

.foo {
  @include foo(1);
}

.foo {
  @include foo(1, 2);
}

.foo {
  @include foo((1, 2));
}
```

The console gives the desired results:

```
DEBUG: 1
DEBUG: 2
DEBUG: 1
```

If you do this, however, the list must be the last argument of the mixin (or function).

Comment: Thanks. Got two solutions.