# Sass nested list appears to be using nested values at root level

Tags: arrays, sass

I have a Sass array (a "list") that has two items. Each item is itself a list with two items. However, when testing the length of the parent list, I get some very strange behaviour:

```
$array: (
    ('a', 'b','c'),
    ('d','e','f')
);

* { length: length($array); }
// -> length: 2
```

vs:

```
$array: (
    ('a', 'b','c')
);

* { length: length($array); }
// -> length: 3
```

Why does Sass appear to be using the inner list if the outer list only has one value?

Comment: possible duplicate of [A singleton list of list is automatically decomposed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21800079/a-singleton-list-of-list-is-automatically-decomposed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a trailing comma to represent a nested list with a single element. From [SASS reference](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#lists):

> Comma-separated lists may have a trailing comma. This is especially useful because it allows you to represent a single-element list. For example, (1,) is a list containing 1 and (1 2 3,) is a comma-separated list containing a space-separated list containing 1, 2, and 3.

So, in your case, this would be the code:

```
$array: (
  ('a', 'b','c'),
):
```

You can also use these alternatives:

```
// Alternative 1
$array: 'a' 'b' 'c',;

// Alternative 2
$array: ();
$array: append($array,('a', 'b','c'));
```